# How can one rsync from a file and delete superfluous files/dirs on destination

Tags: linux, sync, rsync

When using `rsync --files-from=$FILE` I would like to delete all files and directories in the destination that are not listed in the file.

e.g

```bsh
mkdir /tmp/sync
cd /tmp/sync
mkdir left right
touch left/only_left right/only_right
echo /tmp/sync/left/only_left > tosync
rsync \
  --dry-run \
  --itemize-changes \
  --files-from=/tmp/sync/tosync \
  --progress \
  --human-readable \
  --prune-empty-dirs \
  --delete-after \
  --inplace \
  / /tmp/sync/right/
```

outputs

```
cd+++++++++ tmp/
cd+++++++++ tmp/sync/
cd+++++++++ tmp/sync/left/
>f+++++++++ tmp/sync/left/only_left
```

and `find /tmp/sync/right` outputs

```
find right/
right/
right/only_right
right/tmp
right/tmp/sync
right/tmp/sync/left
right/tmp/sync/left/only_left
```

I however expect "only_right" to be deleted, which it isn't. How does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsync will delete destination-only files when recursively comparing the content of directories.

You then need the files in 'tosync' to be relative to the source directory.

Building on your example, to get the behaviour you need, this works:

```
echo 'only_left' > /tmp/sync/tosync

rsync --dry-run --itemize-changes \
--delete --recursive \
--include-from=/tmp/sync/tosync \
--exclude=* /tmp/sync/left/ /tmp/sync/right/
```

Comment: `right/only_right` still isn't deleted with this.

Comment: Ah! `--delete-excluded` did the trick!

Comment: Care to mark the answer as good?